# Android WebView post + custom headers

Tags: android, android-webview

My initial WebView request looks like this:

```
webView.postUrl(url, postData);
```

I need to be able to set the Content-Type header for this request. `Content-Type = application/json`

How can I do this for API 8? 
I tried with `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` but it never gets called. I heard this only works with GET, but I have to use POST.